# Need help building a node sFTP with ssh2 to connect with vs code (sFTP extension)

Tags: node.js, server, sftp, ssh2

I'm trying to build a sFTP server for an application because I need to authenticate users from an existing DB and I don't want to synch them. So I've used ssh2 to do so and I mostly got it to work but when I try to connect via the SFTP (by Natizyskunk) extension in VS Code it loops forever and on the server side I get :

...

READDIR 290 <Buffer 2f 68 6f 6d 65 2f 64 65 62 69 61 6e 2f 63 6c 69 65 6e 74 46 69 6c 65 73>

READDIR 291 <Buffer 2f 68 6f 6d 65 2f 64 65 62 69 61 6e 2f 63 6c 69 65 6e 74 46 69 6c 65 73>

READDIR 292 <Buffer 2f 68 6f 6d 65 2f 64 65 62 69 61 6e 2f 63 6c 69 65 6e 74 46 69 6c 65 73>

^C

What am I doing wrong ?

Where can I find information on what exactly is needed for each actions (READDIR, OPENDIR, etc.) ?

Here is the cb for READDIR:

```
.on('READDIR', function (reqid, handle) {
        console.log('READDIR', reqid, handle)
        if (handle && openDirs[handle.toString()]) {
            const path = openDirs[handle.toString()];
            const dir = fs.readdirSync(path, { withFileTypes: true });
            const entries = dir.map(dirent => {
                const stats = fs.statSync(path + '/' + dirent.name);
                return {
                    filename: dirent.name,
                    longname: `${stats.mode} ${stats.uid} ${stats.gid} ${stats.size} ${stats.mtime} ${dirent.name}`,
                    attrs: stats
                };
            });
            sftp.name(reqid, entries);
        } else {
            sftp.status(reqid, 4);
        }
    })
```

Here's the github page for the project : https://github.com/GPharand/sFTP/blob/main/sftpServer.js (main file is sftpServer.js )

// SFTP extension Config file

```
{
    "name": "My sFTP Server",
    "host": "218.118.168.148", // Fake ip address 
    "protocol": "sftp",
    "port": 2222,
    "username": "username",
    "password": "password",
    "remotePath": "/home/debian/clientFiles",
    "uploadOnSave": false,
    "useTempFile": false,
    "openSsh": false
}
```

Here's the github page for the project : https://github.com/GPharand/sFTP/blob/main/sftpServer.js (main file is sftpServer.js )

Thanks for you help

I'm trying to acheive a workable connection between VS code (SFTP) and my server so my user can edit their scripts on my platform.